# How to call serverside function with button click in jQuery uidialogbox?

Tags: c#, jquery

If I add a serverside function in masterlayout, the popup will display in all the pages. However, once I click the "no" button, it doesn't show anymore. For that, I have to use session, but we can't set the session value in jQuery.

The code behind I use in masterlayout is:

```
     <script runat="server">
      protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Session["sesvalue"] = 1;

      }
     </script>
```

but the method doesn't fire on button click

Answer (score 3):

Your method must have static atribute.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MethodName()
{
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to call a server-side function from jQuery is via an ajax request. You don't need to put anything in Session, you can simply pass the value from the client side as an parameter to the function on the server side. Here's an example:

```
function ShowDialogAndCallServerSideFunction()
{
    var $dialog = $('<div class="dialog"></div>')
    .html('Dialog content goes here')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 320,
        title: 'Title goes here',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "No",
                click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            },
            {
                text: "Yes",
                click: function() {

                        $.ajax({
                            "type": "POST",
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "url": "WebServiceUrl.asmx/MethodName",
                            "data": "{'parameter': " + your_parameterHere + " }",
                            "success": function(result) {
                                //handle success here
                            },
                            "error": function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                //handle any errors here
                            }
                        });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

On the server side, you can have a Web Service - called WebServiceUrl on my example-:

```
[WebMethod]
public void MethodName(string parameter)
{
   //the value received in 'parameter' is the value passed from the client-side via jQuery
}
```